# TclOO : Assign "null" value to object

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to assign a `null` value to object ? and in a second time check if my object is `null`.
This [page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M58) seems to tell me that it is not possible to control if an object is `null` so I guess it is not possible to assign a `null` value, but I’d like to be sure.

Comment: "null" isn't really a concept tcl has... The closest is a variable holding an empty string, but objects aren't variables.

Comment: @Shawn I can write this `if {[my method] eq ""} {return ""}` ?

Comment: Inside another method? If you want/need to, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl (deliberately!) does not have a null in its value system at all; the closest you get is to have a variable (or dictionary key) unset/not existing. The implementation of various key C APIs inside Tcl use `NULL` (such as `Tcl_ObjGetVar2()`, which is what most other variable read operations sit on top of) to indicate a non-existing case (which might or might not be an error, depending on what's being expected).

There are a few cases where you need something more than that, such as when interfacing to an SQL database or to a JSON parser. You'll need to read the documentation for such things, but they'll do things like allowing you to nominate a special string to use instead (such as `"null"` or the empty string) or allowing you to see that a result set element should be present but not actually having the associated key present.

Comment: TclOO itself doesn't have a null… because Tcl doesn't. Nominate a special object if you want. I'd suggest calling it `null`…

Comment: In support of Donal's suggestion, this approach has been referred to as [NULL OBJECT](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/273448.273450) (or VOID OBJECT).